# How to know what SETS are ON in SQL PLUS?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Is there a way in SQL Plus to know the state of all the SET commands?

For example whether or not WRAP is set to OFF or to ON, etc..

I've searched online and I couldn't find anything. 
I also thought it might be something similar to the SET from CMD, but if you try this:

```
SET
```

You get:

> SP2-0545: SET command requires an argument.

**How can I get the value of all the current SETs?**

In case I am not being clear, I want to know if there is a command similar to this:

```
SHOW SETS
```

That will return something like

```
WRAP ON 
LONG 3000
LINESIZE 344
VERIFY OFF
etc..
```

Comment: It's been many years and I don't have sqlplus console handy, but do try SHOW ALL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`SHOW`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve041.htm) command:

- `SHOW ALL` - lists the settings of all `SHOW` options, except `ERRORS` and `SGA`, in alphabetical order.
- `SHOW PARAMETERS` or `SHOW PARAMETERS parameter_name` - displays the current values for one or more initialization parameters; without any string following the command it displays all initialization parameters. You need `SELECT ON V_$PARAMETER` object privileges to use the `PARAMETERS` clause.
- `SHOW SPPARAMETERS` or `SHOW SPPARAMETERS parameter_name` - As for `SHOW PARAMETERS` except this displays current values for initialization parameters for all instances.

There are also other options associated with `SHOW` including (see the link above for further options):

- `SHOW ERRORS` or `SHOW ERRORS {FUNCTION | PROCEDURE | PACKAGE | PACKAGE BODY | TRIGGER | VIEW | TYPE | TYPE BODY | DIMENSION | JAVA CLASS} SCHEMA.NAME` - Shows the compilation errors of a stored procedure (includes stored functions, procedures, and packages). When you specify `SHOW ERRORS` with no arguments, SQL*Plus shows compilation errors for the most recently created or altered stored procedure. When you specify the type and the name of the PL/SQL stored procedure, SQL*Plus shows errors for that stored procedure.
- `SHOW SGA` - displays information about the current instance's System Global Area. You need `SELECT ON V_$SGA` object privileges.
- `SHOW RECYCLEBIN` - Shows objects in the recycle bin that can be reverted with the `FLASHBACK BEFORE DROP` command.